# How to store data on the internet for an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I know this is a pretty simple question, but I've looked through all of my iOS textbook and can't seem to find out how people do this. I just want to store and edit an array on the internet. That is, let's say all of the data for my application is stored in an NSMutableArray. Ignoring the complications that occur with people editing the array at the same time, how would I allow multiple people to go into my app and then through that app access and edit the NSMutableArray for others to see?

Comment: Study as much as you can on Web Services and Databases before trying to implement anything. Jumping into Amazon AWS will have you lost and confused without the foundations

Comment: Hey I don't know why this was put on hold. All the answers helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of options here, some of which were listed by @Zaph. The most common scenario to share data between a ton of random users is to setup your own server to run an API that you app will be able to communicate with. This is commonly referred to as the "Backend". The solutions here are vast, written in many different languages and sometimes even provided by third parties services. My advice is to pickup a simple, easy to learn server-side setup like Ruby-on-Rails, then deploy test app on Heroku as they provide free accounts to play with.

Comment: Thank you! If I decided I wanted to use Amazon AWS, how would they be helpful to me? Would I use their EC2 framework?

Comment: Yes, but this requires you to not only learn some server side framework, but learn how to deploy a server using apache, load balancers, dns managers, database instances etc... If you are simply experimenting, start with something like heroku which offers all this with nearly zero config and for free. Then as you learn more and want to customize more, expand to EC2 or rackspace or something else like that

Comment: Do I need to use anything besides Objective-C for Heroku? It looks like I have to use python or some other non-Objective-C language to set up the server is that true?

Comment: Yes that is true. I recommend Ruby on Rails as it is quite easy to get started, but you could use a php server or something else if you felt more comfortable.

Comment: OK cool so I really don't want to learn another technology. I'm going to use Parse. Thanks so much for your help if I could upvote you a million times I would.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the options @coneybeare provided some others include DropBox, Parse and Azure.

Dropbox requires each user so setup an account.

Parse and Azure have rather easy APIs but you will be paying past the free tier.

Comment: iCloud won't work for multiple users.